# Regex - any printable character except 1-9 or a-zA-Z

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

In my Rails app, I am trying to validate that a password string includes any printable characters that are not the numbers 1-9 or the alphabetic characters a-zA-Z.

I am aware that "printable characters" can be expressed with `[:print:]`, and "not numerical or alphabetical" can be expressed as `/[^1-9a-z]/i`, but I am not sure how to combine the two.

For example, I have tried the below but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I amend this correctly?

```rb
# This code is inside my model
validates :password, format: { with: /(?=.*[[:print:]^1-9a-z])/i }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [character class subtraction in ruby.](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction_javaruby)

For example, to match english lowercase letters that are not vowels in ruby you can use the following regex. It allows you to "subtract" characters aeiou from the character set a-z.

```
regex = /[a-z&&[^aeiou]]/
test_string = 'some random letters'
test_string.scan(regex) do |match|
   puts match.to_s
end
# Outputs: s m r n d m l t t r s
```

Similarly, to match all printed characters that are not `a-zA-Z0-9` in ruby, we "subtract" the character set `[0-9a-zA-Z]` from `[:print:]` as shown below.

```
regex = /[[:print:]&&[^0-9a-zA-Z]]/
test_string = 'ThisIsARandomString453$nf35#@_1;;'
test_string.scan(regex) do |match|
  puts match.to_s
end
# Outputs: $ # @ _ ; ;
```

Comment: Thank you! The explanation about character subtraction was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, maybe

```
/[^0-9a-z&&[\x20-\x7E]]+/i
```

or,

```
/[^0-9a-z&&[\p{Print}]]+/i
```

might be a bit closer to what you have in mind:

#### Test

```
re = /[^0-9a-z&&[\x20-\x7E]]+/i
str = 'abc
ABc
~~'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### Output

```
~~
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ePZyK6/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/ePZyK6/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

Comment: I am accepting the other answer because they included an explanation of the regexes, but thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your requirements and [looking at the ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table.svg) I ended up with [`[\x20-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7E]`](https://regex101.com/r/7c718S/1) (or without hex syntax [`` [ -/:-@[-`{-~] ``](https://regex101.com/r/7c718S/3)).

Using a [POSIX character class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions#Character_classes)

> `[:punct:]`... *punctuation* (all graphic characters except letters and digits)

it looks like, this can be expressed by [**just punctuation and space**](https://regex101.com/r/7c718S/2).

```
[[:punct:] ]
```

[image]